# How to know which part of .gitignore that is actually responsible for ignoring some file?

Tags: git, gitignore

Say I have `.gitignore`:

```
x64/
x86/
bin/
obj/
FileA
FileB
FileC
etc..
```

Now when I build, all build files that I want to ignore, are actually being ignored. However, the build fails for a missing file (Call it FileX).

When I add FileX to the project, it builds fine with no errors. However, GIT does not see that I added that file, and when I do `git status --ignored`, I see the file under `untracked files`.

I tried the solution in [undo git assume unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195861/undo-git-update-index-assume-unchanged-file) with no success.

Why this file is being ignored and I did not add it to .gitignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain which gitignore rule is ignoring my file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/explain-which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure why this file is being ignored, type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/FileX
```

You will see the actual `.gitignore` file responsible for its current ignored state.
If the output of that command is empty, that means the file is simply untracked, ready to be added.

Comment: Briliant! The name of FileX had `lib` in it, and I added `**lib` into my .gitignore in order to ignore everything that goes under LIB directories

Comment: @SandraK Why not `lib/` to ignore the content of a folder named `lib`?

Comment: `git: 'check-ignore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @cnst It is (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) since Git 1.8.2 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23928523/6309). Sept 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953923/6309